# My website's fonts and images render differently on Chrome and Brave browsers

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, browser, brave

So I have a following issue. I'm testing my website's code, and now after hosting the website, it renders images and fonts differently across Brave and Chrome.

I know browsers generally have different rendering engines, but Chrome and Brave are both using Blink as their rendering engine.

Eg. Brave displays my site correctly as it should, but Chrome for some reason does not. Please take a look at images below:

[image: Brave browser]

Above is the website being open in Brave browser.

But now, when I open it in Chrome:

[image: Chrome browser]

The image enlarges itself and removes all margins by the looks of it, and already used font gets displayed incorrectly.

I understand that every browser differs in terms how they render certain elements.
Shouldn't at least Brave display the same thing as Chrome or vice versa if they have the same rendering engines?

I apologize for not leaving the code here as I am currently unable to do so. I can attach my HTML and CSS code additionally afterwards.

Any advice would help a lot. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Different browsers have different security policies and restrictions. Have a look at the console in your inspector in Chrome, to see if Chrome has refused to load some part of your code, and if so, the reason why.